# Can the Balrog be used before going into decline?

Tags: small-world-underground

My friends and I had an argument over this the other night. The rules say that the Balrog can be used at "any point during your turn." So I attempted to use him to ruin my friends day (taking out one of his places of power) and then go into decline. He claimed that I could not do this as I had started conquest by moving the Balrog and therefore could not decline. I countered with the "Any point during my turn." would imply I could do it pre-conquest as that is still during my turn. I searched elsewhere on the internet but only found discussion boards and forums with similar arguments to the one my friend and I had.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's actually an [official ruling on this very point by Days of Wonder](http://www.daysofwonder.com/en/msg/?th=22605&start=0) in the SWU FAQ:

> Q.If my active Race controls the Pentacle, may I move the Balrog, then
> enter in Decline?
>
> A.Yes, since the Balrog may be moved "at any point
> during [your] turn".

Some people may not like this ruling very much, but I don't think its existence can be denied!